# How to convert 64-bit floating point number to readable integer format in python

Tags: python

I have some output coming in below format :

```
  {
    "start": 1494384255611,
    "end": 1494384285611,
    "min": 439169092894,
    "avg": 439176179114.5,
    "median": 439169092894,
    "max": 439183265335,
    "sum": 878352358229,
    "samples": 1,
    "empty": false
  }
```

As I found out, the values mentioned in above dictionary are 64-bit floating point number. The data here represents CPU usage of a system, so I was expecting it not to exceed 100 (should be in percentage).

So I'd like to convert it to the required format in python.

I've tried using base64 encode/decode functions but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In order to have a percentage, you have to divide by something. What's the appropriate value to divide by here?

Answer (score -1):

The best way I know is to use [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/index.html) library. You can format numbers (integers), floats, date, etc.

Here is an example:

```
data = {
    "start": 1494384255611,
    "end": 1494384285611,
    "min": 439169092894,
    "avg": 439176179114.5,
    "median": 439169092894,
    "max": 439183265335,
    "sum": 878352358229
}

import babel.numbers
pretty = {key: babel.numbers.format_number(value, locale='en_US')
    for key, value in data.items()}
```

With:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(pretty)
```

You'll get:

```
{'avg': '439,176,179,114.5',
 'end': '1,494,384,285,611',
 'max': '439,183,265,335',
 'median': '439,169,092,894',
 'min': '439,169,092,894',
 'start': '1,494,384,255,611',
 'sum': '878,352,358,229'}
```

You can also use `format_decimal()` for floating point numbers:

```
pretty = {key: babel.numbers.format_decimal(value, locale='en_US')
    for key, value in data.items()}
```

See the [documentation](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/numbers.html).